# Conditionally bulk move a list documents from one collection to another

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I receive from a service a list of documents which are expired. I want to remove these documents from my main collection into an archive collection. Some of the documents I receive will not be in my main collection, and I want to ignore these documents.

I can do this by first finding the document in my main collection, and if I find it inserting the document into the archive, then deleting it from the main collection when that is successful.

Is it possible to do this kind of conditional moving using bulk operations? I need this to work reasonably quickly for potentially thousands of documents at a time.

Comment: node.js - I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can batch the finding, inserting, and deleting operations. You can use a [bulk write operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) for insertion. It sounds like you have a list of `_id`'s or something similar for your documents that are you using to locate the documents in the main collection. You should batch the find's into groups of 1-2 thousand using `$in`:

```
> my_cursor = db.main.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [ **1-2K _id's** ] } })
```

If an `_id` isn't present in the main collection, then no big deal. Insert the results of the cursor using a bulk operation:

```
> my_bulk_insert = db.archive.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> my_cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    my_bulk_insert.insert(doc)
}
> my_bulk_insert.execute()
```

You will be informed about any errors. Then remove the docs from main once the insertion is successful

```
> db.main.remove({ "_id" : { "$in" : [ **1-2K _id's** ] } })
```